# @ char as a key in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

I tried using the @ char as a key in a NSDictionary and my application simply crashes. I searched for "invalid" key names, could not find the @"@" anywhere. If I use something else than @"@" it all works fine.

I have a list of comanies, I get the first letter of each company and then I am creating a NSMutableDictionary entry containing the first letter as the key and a NSMutableArray as the value.

```
NSMutableDictionary indexDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// here we have a loop on companyName
{
NSString *fristLetter = [[companyName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfIndexedCompanies = [indexDictionary valueForKey:firstLetter];

    if (arrayOfIndexedCompanies) {
       [arrayOfIndexedCompanies addObject:companyName]
    }
    else {
       NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
       [indexDictionary setObject:newArray forKey:firstLetter];
       [newArray addObject:companyName];
    }
}
```

I enabled breakpoint break on throw and it stops at the [indexDictionary valueForKey:firstLetter]... only when firstLetter is a @"@".
I had an if saying:

```
if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"@"]) {
    firstLetter = @"A";
}
```

and this works fine, it places the @ starting companies in the A section correctly. If I am letting the firstLetter unchanged (leaving it as @"@") the application will crash.

Also, this is not really my code, I am just trying to fix it, I am not quite familiar with ObjC and Foundation so please be gentle.

Comment: I was trying to find out if anybody else had the same problem and is there a way to escape/fix this and use @ as a key ?

Comment: Put that in the question then. (Though skip the "does anybody else experience this" part, as it isn't really the thing to ask here) Also, why would you want to?

Comment: I have a list of entity names, some of them are starting with @, I am building the sections in a table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :)

Specifically, this bit :

> If key does not start with “@”, invokes objectForKey:. If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes [super valueForKey:] with the rest of the key.

I guess that `super valueForKey:` isn't happy being called :)

To fix it, just call `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`

Answer (score 1):

Using the string `@"@"` as a dictionary key works just fine:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test 1", @"@", @"Test 2", @"Another @", nil];
NSString *result = [dict objectForKey:@"@"];
NSLog(@"%@", result); 
// --> Test 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with @"\u0040"

Comment: Tried replacing @"@" with @"\u0040" and it still fails. It should be the same char anyway :)